# Problem generating foreign key in EF Code First - Unable to determine the principal end of an association

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first

I am trying to enable migrations on a new db that includes the following table relationship:
[image: relationship]

where **HolderID** can be NULL. Running **enable-migrations** gives the error message of "*Unable to determine the principal end of an association*"

My 2 classes are as follows:

```
public class Competitor
{
    [Key]
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string FullName { get { return string.Format("{0} {1}", FirstName, LastName); } }

    public virtual Championship Championship { get; set; }
}

public class Championship
{
    [Key]
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int? HolderID { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("HolderID")]
    public virtual Competitor Holder { get; set; }
}
```

I don't understand how I need to correct my model to reflect the desired database schema structure. I would prefer to use Annotations over fluent api, if possible.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public virtual Championship Championship { get; set; }
```

needed to be

```
public virtual ICollection<Championship> Championships { get; set; }
```